# EXCEPTION in before the end of the loop

Tags: sql, oracle, for-loop, exception, plsql

I'm trying to raise an EXCEPTION after the end of the inner loop and continue the outer loop i get the following error:

> ERROR at line 29:
>   ORA-06550: line 29, column 6:
>   PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "EXCEPTION" when expecting one of the following:
>   ( begin case declare end exit for goto if loop mod null
>   pragma raise return select update while with 
>     <<
>   continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
>   savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge

Here is my code:

```
DECLARE
TOTAL_ZERO  EXCEPTION;
client_rec E_CLIENT%ROWTYPE;
commande_rec E_COMMANDE%ROWTYPE;
total_client integer:=0;
total_commande integer:=0;
i integer:=1;
j integer:=1;
Nombre_Commande integer:=0;
Total_paye E_COMMANDE.TOTAL%TYPE:=0;
BEGIN
select count (*) into total_commande from E_COMMANDE;
select count (*) into total_client from E_CLIENT;
FOR j IN 1 .. total_client LOOP
    select * into client_rec from E_CLIENT where NO=j;
    FOR i IN 1 .. total_commande LOOP

        select  * into commande_rec from E_COMMANDE where NO=i;
        IF EXTRACT(YEAR FROM commande_rec.DATE_COMMANDE)=2004 THEN
            IF commande_rec.CLIENT_NO = j THEN
                Nombre_Commande:=Nombre_Commande+1;
                Total_paye := Total_paye + commande_rec.TOTAL;
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    IF Nombre_Commande=0 THEN RAISE TOTAL_ZERO; END IF;
    dbms_output.put_line('Numero client     ' || client_rec.NO || '     Nom client      ' || client_rec.NOM || ': ');
    dbms_output.put_line('total :   ' || Total_paye || '    ' || 'Nombre_Commande' || Nombre_Commande);
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN TOTAL_ZERO THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('---------ERROR----------');
    Nombre_Commande:=0;
    Total_paye:=0;


END LOOP;
END;
/
```

PS: I'm using SQLplus Oracle 11gR2 on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed a end loop just before the exception statement. And I removed the end loop after the exception.
An exception (if used) goes always with the begin and end statement.

Good luck.

```
DECLARE
  TOTAL_ZERO  EXCEPTION;
  client_rec E_CLIENT%ROWTYPE;
  commande_rec E_COMMANDE%ROWTYPE;
  total_client integer:=0;
  total_commande integer:=0;
  i integer:=1;
  j integer:=1;
  Nombre_Commande integer:=0;
  Total_paye E_COMMANDE.TOTAL%TYPE:=0;
BEGIN
  select count (*) into total_commande from E_COMMANDE;
  select count (*) into total_client from E_CLIENT;
  FOR j IN 1 .. total_client LOOP
    select * into client_rec from E_CLIENT where NO=j;
    FOR i IN 1 .. total_commande LOOP

        select  * into commande_rec from E_COMMANDE where NO=i;
        IF EXTRACT(YEAR FROM commande_rec.DATE_COMMANDE)=2004 THEN
            IF commande_rec.CLIENT_NO = j THEN
                Nombre_Commande:=Nombre_Commande+1;
                Total_paye := Total_paye + commande_rec.TOTAL;
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    IF Nombre_Commande=0 THEN RAISE TOTAL_ZERO; END IF;
    dbms_output.put_line('Numero client     ' || client_rec.NO || '     Nom client      ' || client_rec.NOM || ': ');
    dbms_output.put_line('total :   ' || Total_paye || '    ' || 'Nombre_Commande' || Nombre_Commande);
  END LOOP;   ---> !!!!
EXCEPTION
    WHEN TOTAL_ZERO THEN
      dbms_output.put_line('---------ERROR----------');
      Nombre_Commande:=0;
      Total_paye:=0;

END;
/
```

Comment: I want the first loop to continue after the exception thats why i put the END LOOP after the exception

Comment: By the way, the `i` and `j` variables you declare at the top aren't used. The `for i in ... loop` construction implicitly declares its own.